# Build urls with parameters

Tags: php, url

I'm trying to generate a URL similar to 
[https://website.com/oltp-­‐web/processTransaction?REQUEST_TYPE=2&MID=5](https://website.com/oltp-%C2%AD%E2%80%90web/processTransaction?REQUEST_TYPE=2&MID=5)

I'm using PHP's `http_build_query` function but it's not generating a proper URL.
Code sample:

```
<?php 
$parameters =array(
'https://pguat.paytm.com/oltp-­‐web/processTransaction?',
'REQUEST_TYPE'=>'2',
'MID'=>'5');
  $url = http_build_query($parameters);
  echo $url;
 ?>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your first array value is *not* a parameter. It's the URL you want to add the query string to. `http_build_query()` builds query strings, not entire URLs. So remove that value and then append the results of `http_build_query()` to it:

```
$parameters =array(
    'REQUEST_TYPE'=>'2',
    'MID'=>'5'
);
$url = 'https://pguat.paytm.com/oltp-­‐web/processTransaction?' . http_build_query($parameters);
```